# INP field report logs some element that is not even listening to any interactive events. What should I fix?

Tags: interaction-to-next-paint

I just received some data from Google Web Vitals JS Library. Any after refining the reports, I noticed that many huge INP penalty happened on an element that is not even clickable.

[image]

And the dom structure is like this:

[image]

The `<b>` itself is not a button, just wrapped inside the button. What should I fix? How can I debug this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. The web-vitals.js library returns the element clicked (using [`event.target`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals/blob/a6024e4a5bef95a310ef037079b700403b5f3c38/src/attribution/onINP.ts#L48-L50)), even if that click bubbles up to a parent element to be handled.

The Event Timing API doesn't include a [`currentTarget`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666647/on-button-click-i-get-event-of-child-element) to get the actual event handler but even if it did that would be less useful if the event handler is at a much higher level (e.g. the document).

Additionally, the reason it doesn't include `currentTarget` is that INP  does not event require an explicit event handler. Just clicking on an non-interactive element (e.g. double clicking text to highlight it) can be the INP event, especially if the main thread is blocked and unable to handle that "no-op" click. Now most of those will be quick even if the main thread is busy as most modern browsers handle most of those sorts of browser-UI events (highlighting, scrolling...etc.) separate to the main thread, but they still count as INP-potential events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I’d like to ask one more question: Will user-select:none or pointer-event:none help improve the INP?

Comment: I would advise against that as a solution for INP issues. While `pointer-event:none` can prevent some event handlers being triggered, if the event handlers exist, they presumably exist for a reason? Better to remove them if they are not needed, rather than pretend they don't exist. Also, as per my last comment, you don't even need an event handler to trigger INP. `user-select:none` is unlikely to help INP - selecting text is usually very quick, as I said, and turning it off when a user expects it is just likely to frustrate the user for no real benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and guidelines. I found it really hard to locate the issue in my users cases because every time I use my web page, the INP score including all other metrics are all perfect. I find it very hard to reproduce the failure cases. Is there anything else I can do with the reports? Thanks so much for your time and patience.

Comment: Check the browser device types. Mobile browsers are often much less powerful. You can use CPU throttling in DevTools to simulate this, or debug on an Android device directly and monitor: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks very much for your ideas. Very doable methods! Thanks!